# Drools-Compare properties of 2 objects

Tags: drools

I have a requirement to determine which train to choose to assign an Employee to.

Let's say I have 2 trains with properties as:

```
Train 1                      Train 2
trainID=1                    trainID=2
passengerCount=100           passengerCount=150
numberOfBoxes=12             numberOfBoxes=7
```

If I pass both these objects to Drools and check like

```
$train1 : TrainProperties($pasCnt : passengerCount) 
    $train2 : TrainProperties($pasCnt2 : passengerCount > $pasCnt)  
then    
    Sysout("Train 2 is more important")
end
```

Now I have to add more conditions based on numberOfBoxes. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Drools Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_comma_separated_and), you can use a `,` to create multiple `AND` conditions inside a pattern. You can also use `||` to create `OR`.

So, in your case, you could do something like this:

```
when
    $train1 : TrainProperties($pasCnt : passengerCount, $boxes: numberOfBoxes) 
    $train2 : TrainProperties($pasCnt2 : passengerCount > $pasCnt, numberOfBoxes > $boxes )  
then    
    Sysout("Train 2 is more important")
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks Esteban... I think I didnt write it completely.

Comment: Thanks Esteban... I think I didnt write it completely. What is happening is : When I send train1 and train object as facts: and when i retrieve these objects in drool file, the order doesn't seem to be the same.. If I have sent Train1 first, I get Train2 data in drool file.. And it is not consistent, In Rule1 it is Train2 first, and in other Rule, some other Train data comes first. Is there a way I maintain the same order in drool file what I am sending as facts.. I hope I have made myself clear about the issue I am facing

Comment: No, there is not. You should write your rules in a way that the order in which the facts come into the session doesn't affect them. If the order is really important in your case, then you may need to ask yourself if Drools (or any production rules engine) is the best fit for you.

Comment: Of course you can do something like `$train1: Train(id == 1) $train2: Train(id == 2)`, but that will make your rules extremely brittle.